# Error 403 in React fetching data from the Django endpoint

Tags: python, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, http-status-code-403

I am developing a Hostel Management system using React and Django. The React runs on `localhost:3000` while the django-rest-api runs on `localhost:8000`.

Currently, upon login in `localhost:8000/api/login`, I display user data in JSON format on `localhost:8000/api/user`.
While upon login from frontend `localhost:3000`, The server displays that a user has logged in by returning status 200 and the `last_login` attribute on the `sqlite3` database gets updated too. But as I redirect the user too `localhost:3000/api/student-view`, I get a 403 forbidden error.

I validate user in `views.py`

```
class UserLogin(APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        assert validate_username(data)
        assert validate_password(data)
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=data)  ## Validates user data
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.check_user(data)
            login(request, user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```
class UserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = StudentViewSerializer(request.user)
        return Response({"user": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I `POST` the data to the server from `Login.js`. Server logs that the user is valid here.

```
function submitLogin(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        client.post(
        "/api/login",
        {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }, {withCredentials: true}
        ).then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        navigate("/student-view", {replace: true});
      }
      return response; 
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error", err)
    })
}
```

Finally `StudentView.js` should make a `GET` from `localhost:3000/api/user`, which gives a 403.

```
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
});


function StudentView() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    client
      .get("/api/user")
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data);
        setPosts(result.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((data) => {
        return (
          <div key={data.id}>
            <h4>{data.title}</h4>
            <p>{data.body}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also in my `settings.py`,

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
"http://localhost:3000",
"http://127.0.0.1",
"http://0.0.0.0",
```

]

Comment: Check the network console on the browser when you get 403  - this feels like it could be to missing CORS support.

Comment: The errors on the console are :  AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 403', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Comment: network tab does not show stuff like that ..

Comment: In that the Status is 403 and the type is "xhr". Is that what I should refer to?

Comment: Access Control Allow Origin is set to "localhost://3000"
Access-Control-Allow-control is true